# Js - Diferencia entra "objeto.propiedad" vs "objeto[propiedad]"

Tags: javascript, objeto

Estoy con una confusión entre el uso de "objeto.propiedad" vs "objeto[propiedad]"

Recorro la cadena de texto. (Solo hablare del primer ciclo)

1- El primer console.log devuelva la letra (h)

2- El segundo console.log devuelve el valor 1, de la propiedad "h" del objeto "counts"

3- Teniendo en cosideracion que `par[i]` es "h" y que "h"  existe en el objeto "counts"
¿Porque al usar `counts.par[i]` que tecnicamente es igual a decir `counts[h]` Me lanza un error?

```js
let par = "hola"

let counts = {
  h:1
};

for(let i=0; i<3;i++){
    console.log(par[i])  //Devuelve "h" "o" ..etc
    console.log(counts.h) //Deuelve 1. El valor de la propiedad "h" en el objeto counts
    console.log(counts.par[i])  //Devuelve que no esta definido
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los corchetes son útiles cuando el nombre de la propiedad es dinámico, por ejemplo si está dentro de una variable `objeto["valor_de_la_variable"]`. Esto no se puede hacer con la notación de `.variable`

Cuando utilizamos corchetes en un string este último es tratado como el `object` ["h","o","l","a"].

Entonces `par[o]` lo podemos usar como nombre de propiedad si lo usamos dento de corchetes `[par[o]]`, no lo podemos usar en la notacion de `.propiedad`.

```js
let par = "hola";

let counts = {
  h: 1,
  par2: [1,2,3,4,5]
};

// par[0]) <-- Trata al string como object ["h","o","l","a"]

console.log(counts[par[0]]); // <-- se obtine la propiedad dinámicamente

console.log(counts.par2[1]); // <-- Busca la propiedad par2
```

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente no hay diferencia, solo que la forma objeto[propiedad] se puede acceder utilizando una variable en los corchetes.

Count par no existe en tu planteo. Por eso te da error.